# Mandatory decimal numbers Math Round

Tags: c#, math, rounding

I have a method that returns the perimeter of a triangle. One of the parameters to this method is the precision.

When I call my function specifying the precision I don't get the results I expect. I don't know how I can resolve the problem with `Math.Round`.

```java
public static double TrianglePerimeter(int a, int b, int c, int precision = 2)
{
  if (a < 0 || b < 0 || c < 0 || precision < 2 || precision > 8)
    throw new ArgumentException("wrong arguments");
  
  if (a + b < c || a + c < b || b + c < a)
    throw new ArgumentException("object not exist");

  return Math.Round((double)a+(double)b+(double)c, precision); 
}
```

Example:

1. a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, precision = 3

   - Result = 6.000
2. a = 1, b =  1, c = 1, precision = 5

   - Result = 3.00000

Comment: What results were you expecting that differ from what you got?

Comment: `double` does not _have_ variable precision. `decimal` does, but 6.00 and 6.0000 are effectively the same value. `Round` doesn't change that. If you want to _display_ a certain number of decimals, that should be done outside of the calculation method. Or you can change the method to return a string (but only if it's an assignment and that's what the instructor wants)

Comment: doubles don't have "precision" other than what the name tells you: they're double precision IEEE floating point data types. Any "number of decimal places" only becomes relevant once you convert the number to a string format, so add the appropriate formatting instruction at the point where you're actually writing these numbers to screen. Or to file. Or to a web page. Or whatever else stops it being a true number and instead presents it as a string.

Comment: `if (a + b < c || a + c < b || b + c < a)`, shouldn't that be `if !(a + b < c || a + c < b || b + c < a)` (you forgot the "NOT" operator :-) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, decimal rounding won't get you what you need because 12 = 12.0 = 12.000.  The Round function will only work for you if you actually have significant digits that extend to those decimal places (e.g. 12.0011 would round to 12.001 if you did Math.Round(12.0011, 3);

What you need to do is format the return value as a string with the proper format.  Notice the return result is string, not double. Something like this:

```
    public static string TrianglePerimeterS(int a, int b, int c, int precision = 2)
    {
        if (a < 0 || b < 0 || c < 0 || precision < 2 || precision > 8)
            throw new ArgumentException("wrong arguments");

        if (a + b < c || a + c < b || b + c < a)
            throw new ArgumentException("object not exist");

        // Build the format string in the format of "0.000" if precision is 3
        string formatString = "0." + new string('0', precision);
        double value = Math.Round((double)a + (double)b + (double)c, precision);

        string result = value.ToString(formatString);
        return result;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the people before me have mentioned, you won't get those extra decimal places through *Round()* if no significant numbers extend to those decimal places.

One way of getting the answer in that format is how @John C. did it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74724870/19433977

I think you need to modify your function's mathematical part to be more correct.

```
//Changed input parameters corresponding to sides as double instead of int to cover more cases
public static string TrianglePerimeter(double a, double b, double c, int precision)
    {
        //Used "<=" instead of "<" because the sides can't be 0 either
        if (a <= 0 || b <= 0 || c <= 0 || precision < 2 || precision > 8)
            throw new ArgumentException("Wrong arguments");
        
        //Used "<=" instead of "<" because the sum of sides can't be equal to the 3rd side either
        if (a + b <= c || a + c <= b || b + c <= a)
            throw new ArgumentException("Triangle can't exist");

        string format = "0." + new string('0', precision);
        double value = Math.Round(a + b + c, precision);

        string result = value.ToString(format);
        return result;
     }
```